# Is there an elisp function like "cl-every" that returns nil on lists of unequal length?

Tags: performance, comparison, elisp

I want to compare two lists in elisp using `(cl-every #'eq list1 list2)`. However, this can return `t` if one of the lists is longer than the other, and I don't want that. I could call `length` on the lists, but then I'm traversing each list twice, which is needlessly inefficient. Is there a function like `cl-every` that also checks for equal lengths as well?

Comment: I don't think there is such a function OOTB. I don't think it is hard to implement one. However, `length` is implemented in C and, unless your lists are huge, should not noticeably affect performance. If your lists _are_ huge, you might want to use a Common Lisp instead of Emacs Lisp.

Comment: I guess the other relevant question is, is `equal` smart enough to skip deeply comparing values if two objects are already `eq`?

Comment: That is an easy YES: `equal` descends only if `eq` returns `nil`.

Comment: Ok, if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## OOTB

I don't think there is such a function OOTB.

## Roll your own

I don't think it is hard to implement one, just modify [`cl-every`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.el#n217).

### Length

Note that `length` is implemented in C and, unless your lists are huge, should not noticeably affect performance:

```
(defun list-elements-eq (l1 l2)
  (and (= (length l1)
          (length l2))
       (every #'eq l1 l2)))
```

### Equal

You can also use [`equal`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Equality-Predicates.html) for your lists: since `equal` starts with testing for `eq`, it will be a weaker relationship than what you want.

Beware that in Common Lisp [`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm) may not terminate for circular structures.
Emacs Lisp is "smarter": it detects cicularity:

```
(setq x (list 1))
(setcdr x x)
(setq y (list 1))
(setcdr y y)
(eq x y)
(equal x y)
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (circular-list #1=(1 . #1#))
  equal(#1=(1 . #1#) #2=(1 . #2#))
```

(arguably, it should returns `t` instead).

## Common Lisp

Generally speaking, Common Lisp is a better language for "heavy lifting".

If your lists are huge, you might want to use it instead of Emacs Lisp:

```
(defun list-elements-eq (l1 l2)
  (if (endp l1)
      (endp l2)
      (and (not (endp l2))
           (eq (pop l1) (pop l2))
           (list-elements-eq l1 l2))))
```

This is tail-recursive, and any decent CL will optimize recursion away (possibly depending on the [`optimize`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_optimi.htm) setting).

You don't want to use deep recursion in ELisp (see [Why is there no tail recursion optimization in Emacs lisp, not but like other scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38493904/850781)).

Comment: Side note: I had a quick look at the C implementation of `equal`, and it looked like it used a hash table of seen objects to break cycles. Are you sure it won't terminate for circular structures?